# how to give css for placeholder in kendoUI multiselect

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI.
To apply css for placeholder in textbox I gave like

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-style:normal;        
             opacity:0.6;
            color:grey;
            font-size:14px;
        }
```

I am trying trying to apply css for placeholder in multiselect.
can any one help me how to do that?

Comment: For some reason Kendo defaults to making it black whereas it should be a light gray.

Comment: it's black but they adjusted opacity to make it grey.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to specify the style of the input before focus:

```
.k-multiselect-wrap>.k-input {
   font-style: normal;
   color: #C5C5C5;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

and this to set the style of the input when focused (while the user is typing):

```
.k-multiselect-wrap>.k-input:focus {
   color: #000; /* specify the focused input color */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
.k-multiselect-wrap {
    font-style: normal;
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

or

```
.k-multiselect {
    font-style: normal;
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Depending on what you exactly want

Comment: If I appy the above css then,If I select any element in multiselect,the same css is applying

Comment: How do you want it to look like, as the ones already selected?

Comment: initially placeholder display in multiselect,I want to display this by the above css,and it is working fine.If I select any record in the multiselect then the above css is applying to the selected record ans it is also displaying with 0.6 opacity and in grey color

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want. As far as I understand initially selected options look fine but then I do not get if the problem is how the options are displayed in the drop-down menu or how the new selected options look like, or is any of this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to comment a year later
Anyways, I found the solution using javascript to the same problem:

1.Subscribe to on change event of the kendo multi select:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.MyVar)                          
               .Events(events => events.Change("multiSelectChange"))
                )
```

Then you have declare the function on JavaScript

```
function multiSelectChange() {
        var $multiSelectLists = $(".k-multiselect-wrap");
        $multiSelectLists.each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).find("ul").children().length > 0) {
                $(this).css({ "color": "gray", "opacity": "1.0" });
            }
            else {
                $(this).css({ "color": "gray", "opacity": "0.5" });
            }
        });
     }
```

I had various multi selects in my code, so I do an iteration on all of them on every change of the multi select. I know my code is not very efficient, as I iterate on all of the multi selects on my page and change the CSS of each one each time one of them is changed. Ideally you should not need to iterate all the existing multi selects, but this works fine!